# Adding two strings that could be a float or int values

Tags: java, string, gwt

I have some values in an array that i need to add together. They are not text strings, but rather have values like "35.00" and "2918"

How can I add these together and get a correct result? I will assume that the result should be 2953 but I am getting 295300

The strings can come in like "25.78" and "0.00"

Is there anything I can do to make it more accurate? Unfortunately, I am stuck with GWT.

[image]

I have tried to convert the strings to Big Decimal and then add them but its not completely correct.

```
String n = item.getValue();
a = new BigDecimal(n);

String cheese = item.getValue();
b = new BigDecimal(cheese);

BigDecimal sum;
sum = a.add(b);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What about `Double.valueOf("35.00") + Double.valueOf("2918")`?

Comment: sum_0_g$ has a value of 295300 with a scale of 2, which means it's 2953.00, which is how Big Decimals manage their data - you'll need to look into formatting it or converting it to double BigDecimal#doubleValue().

Comment: This addition should work properly. looks like problem in formatting. can you show code where u are printing sum.

Comment: Double.valueOf("35.00") + Double.valueOf("2918") seems to be working fine. If you add this as a formal answer i can accept it.Thanks

Comment: How is it "not completely correct?" What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: If you care accurate numbers rather than speed of execution, then you should certainly be using `BigDecimal` rather than `float`/`Float` or `double`/`Double`.

Answer (score 0):

Here a basic approach to solve your problem:

```
@Test
public void genericSum() {

    double sum = 0D;
    List<String> elements = Arrays.asList("23.16", "2000", "50.8", "0.00");
    for(String element : elements) {
        try{
            sum += Integer.parseInt(element);   
        }catch(Exception e1) {
            try{
                sum += Double.parseDouble(element);   
            }catch(Exception e2) {

            }   
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);

}
```